# Open specific programms by running a command on my Mac

Tags: javascript, macos

Everyday I work with Slack, Skype, Terminal, Google Drive, Adobe XD and so on.

I open Slack on my left desktop, Terminal in the middle, Google Drive on the right and so on...

It takes me about ~5mins to get settled in every morning.

I've heard there is a way to ease your life and that you could do write a javascript to open all your personal setup when typing in the following:

**command-space > (spotlight search) /start > it will open/start your personal set up**

How can I configure such thing? Or perhaps there is an easier/better way?

Comment: Not sure if JavaScript can do that, bu AppleScript can definitely achieve what you want

Comment: In a additional Os X has native Automator app with which you can create workflows to launch applications or automate flows

Comment: @volna thanks for your quick response. Do you have a link with a guideline for this specific case maybe?

Comment: I don't but I am sure there are plenty tutorials on youtube :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could write a small terminal script that executes a load of the following on after another:

`open /Applications/APPNAME.app`

and then run that from Spotlight. Or you could not shut your Mac down every evening and leave everything where you want it. My mac has an uptime of 40 days at the moment and all's fine.